# By applying the second version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus find the integral:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

The second version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that if $F'(x)=f(x)$ then $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = F(b)-F(a)$.

I need to use this to find a) $\int_{-2}^{-1} \frac{1}{x^3} dx $ and b) $\int_{0}^{x} t \cdot cos(t^2) dt $

Now I can solve both integrals easily enough and get a) $-\frac{3}{8}$ and b) $\frac{1}{2}sin(x^2)$ as my answers. However I don't know what qualifies as using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. I've just integrated as I normally would and got my answers. Do I need to be particularly rigorous or what?

Answer (score 1):

Computing these integrals "easily enough" means using the FTC. That's what the FTC is all about.

The "hard way" would be to rewrite them as limits of Riemann sums and computing these limits "directly". The latter can only be done in special cases, like the following: $\int_0^1 e^x\ dx$.

Comment: So I'm right in just solving them as we were taught in school? I'm only thinking that I need to do something more because this is part of a second year analysis course at university and thought there should be something harder.

Comment: @john.smith: Maybe there is more in the full text of the problem; but otherwise you are done.

Answer (score -1):

we have $\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^{-2}\right)'=\frac{1}{x^3}$ thus we get
$\int_{-2}^{-1}\frac{1}{x^3}dx=\frac{1}{2}(-2)^{-2}-\frac{1}{2}(-1)^{-2}=-\frac{3}{8}$
is it this what you mean?
sorry for my mistake, further we have
$\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin(x^2)\right)'=\frac{1}{2}\cos(x^2)2x=x\cos(x^2)$ and we get
$\int_{0}^{x}t\cos(t^2)dt=\frac{1}{2}\sin(x^2)$

Comment: Well you've got the integral wrong, it's $-\frac{3}{8}$ not $\frac{5}{8}$ but is the idea that I need to begin by showing that differentiating the anti-derivative gives the function I need to integrate?